# Calculating absolute and relative error in matlab issues using False Position Method

Tags: matlab

I am using the function `f = @(x) 2*sin(x) - exp(x)/4-1` in my False Position algorithm. It is given that the root `-5.7591` is the correct root. However, the different methods to calculate error are incorrect in my algorithm. If there was no counter to stop the while loop, it would go on forever whenever I used the absolute approximate (flag = 1) or relative error (flag = 2).

```
flag = 1 means calculate using absolute approx error
flag = 2 means calculate using absolute relative error
flag = 3 means calculate using true error (this one works fine)
```

the range used is [-7,-5] and the loop should stop when the error drops below 10^6

below is the code along with the input and output below it:

```
function [root,counter] = FalsePosition(f,x1,x2,d,flag)

sx1 = x1;
sx2 = x2;

if(f(x1)*f(x2) >= 0)
    disp("x1 and x2 are not correct")
    return
end

while(flag > 3 || flag < 1)
    flag = input("Flag used incorrectly! please enter a value 1 - 3: ");
end


i = 0;
E = d;
while(i < 100 && E >= d)

    x3 = x2 - f(x2)*(x2-x1)/(f(x2)-f(x1));
    i = i + 1;
    if(f(x1)*f(x3) < 0)
            x2 = x3;
            x = x1;
        else
            x1 = x3;
            x = x2;
    end

    if(flag == 1)
        E = abs(x - x3); % abs approx error
    elseif(flag == 2)
        e = abs(x - x3);
        E = e/abs(x3); % abs relative error
    else
        E = abs(f(x3)); % true error
    end
end

counter = i;
root = x3;
if(flag == 1)
    method = "Absolute approximate error";
elseif(flag == 2)
    method = "Absolute relative approximate error";
else
    method = "True absolute error";
end
disp("Method used: " + method);
disp("Brackets: " + sx1 + " and " + sx2);
disp("The root is " + root);
disp("Iterations: " + counter);
disp(" ");
```

Input/Output:

```
>> f = @(x) 2*sin(x) - exp(x)/4-1;
>> [v,c] = FalsePosition(f,-7,-5,10^-6,2)
Method used: Absolute relative approximate error
Brackets: -7 and -5
The root is -5.7591
Iterations: 100


v =

   -5.7591


c =

   100
```

where v is the root and c is the iterations of the while loop

Comment: I think this might be as simple as computer arithmetic issues in calculating `x3`. Try this rearranged version (which limits roundoff error according to wikipedia): `x3 = (f(x2)*x1-f(x1)*x2)/(f(x2)-f(x1))`.

Comment: @David I replaced my original calculation with your suggested one. I still had the same issue. However, I tried testing it by using a different equation `x3 = (x1 + x2)/2` (which is the x3 equation used in bisection method) and that made it work, so I think you are definitely onto something with the issue being x3 equation.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that False Position Method (Along with Secant Method as well) are very sensitive to whatever the initial brackets in the system are. In my example I was using the brackets -7 and -5 which caused issues. I switched to a different (more focused set) of brackets -6 and -5.5 which gives me a desired result:

```
>> [v,c] = FalsePosition(f,-6,-5.5,10^-6,2)
Method used: Absolute relative approximate error
Brackets: -6 and -5.5
The root is -5.7591
Iterations: 13


v =

   -5.7591


c =

    13
```

Answer (score 0):

So there is actually a second workaround I discovered as well. Instead of changing the brackets, it can also be checked if the number of iterations is greater than one and if so, make x = x3 then update x3:

```
function [root,counter] = FalsePosition(funct,x1,x2,d,flag)

f = matlabFunction(funct);
sx1 = x1;
sx2 = x2;

if(f(x1)*f(x2) >= 0)
    disp("x1 and x2 are not correct")
    return
end

while(flag > 3 || flag < 1)
flag = input("Flag used incorrectly! please enter a value 1 - 3: ");
end

x3 = (f(x2)*x1-f(x1)*x2)/(f(x2)-f(x1));
i = 0;
E = d;
while(E >= d)

    x3 = (f(x2)*x1-f(x1)*x2)/(f(x2)-f(x1));
    i = i + 1;
    if(f(x1)*f(x3) < 0)
        x2 = x3;
        x = x1;
    else
        x1 = x3;
        x = x2;
end

if(i > 1)
    x = x3;
    x3 = (f(x2)*x1-f(x1)*x2)/(f(x2)-f(x1));
end

if(flag == 1)
    E = abs(x - x3); % abs approx error
elseif(flag == 2)
    e = abs(x - x3);
    E = e/abs(x3); % abs relative error
else
    E = abs(f(x3)); % true error
end
end

counter = i;
root = x3;
if(flag == 1)
    method = "Absolute approximate error";
elseif(flag == 2)
    method = "Absolute relative approximate error";
else
    method = "True absolute error";
end
disp("Method used: " + method);
disp("Brackets: " + sx1 + " and " + sx2);
disp("The root is " + root);
disp("Iterations: " + counter);
disp(" ");
```

The following if statement was added into the function which fixes the problem

```
if(i > 1)
    x = x3;
    x3 = (f(x2)*x1-f(x1)*x2)/(f(x2)-f(x1));
end
```

Now if I run the same settings with the original brackets I get an answer without an iterative issue:

```
>> [v,c] = FalsePosition(f,-7,-5,10^-6,2)
Method used: Absolute relative approximate error
Brackets: -7 and -5
The root is -5.7591
Iterations: 6


v =

   -5.7591


c =

     6
```

Both these options seem to work but it comes down to a matter of preference